# MySQL Join or Subquery when using functions?

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a table called `customers` and a table named `customer_bills`

And I wanna count the customer bills.

I have a function I have built called `countBills`, it gets (int) `input` and inside it returns `(SELECT count(id) FROM customer_bills WHERE customerId = input)`.

When I use `SELECT id, countBills(id) FROM customers`

What is happening?

Is it `SELECT id, (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM customer_bills) FROM customers`

Or is it `SELECT id, count(customer_bills.id) FROM customers JOIN customer_bills ON customer.id = customer_bills.customerId`

So in short, **Does MySQL know how to optimize query when using functions as it is known that joins are faster than subqueries?**

Comment: First is near to reality than 2nd. But my recommendation is to avoid using such function! The function can do some calculation but don't put in it such subqueries - otherwise the result is slow and heavy query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub queries are always slow than joins. So you should not use function for such easy situation. You
can use this query.

```
SELECT c.id, count(cb.id) FROM customers c JOIN customer_bills cb ON c.id = cb.customerId group by c.id;
```